# How do you make a list with 100 1s in Scala 2.9

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

In earlier versions of Scala you can use List.make(100, 1), but that is now deprecated. What is the new proper way to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As described in the *deprecated* note:

```
@deprecated("use `fill' instead", "2.8.0")
```

try this:

```
List.fill(100)(1)
```

Answer (score 8):

As the documentation says:

```
  List.fill(100)(1)
```